# Django + memcached: generate cached pages automatically?

Tags: django, memcached, django-caching

I am using Django + memcached and have a (hopefully) simple question.

My database is updated once a day. My pages are set to time out after 24 hours.

Is there a way to generate all the pages of the site into the cache once each day, just after the database is updated, in advance of any users coming to them?

I'd like the first user of the day to see the fast-loading cached version, not the slow-loading non-cached version.

I guess I could do this by scraping the site, but is there a neater way?

Comment: Probably not. There isn't necessarily a consistent way URLs are mapped to models. Some URLs are based on model fields, some are not. For non model URL kwargs, there's no consistent programmatic way to generate valid URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to depend on how you have your urls.py set up.

If your urls are all either

- A.) Straight out of the urls.py

or

- B.) Predictable based on your database

If so, you might be able to use django_extensions show_urls

by doing python manage.py show_urls it outputs a list of all the urls.

From there, you can just capture them in a list and loop over them while hitting each one with a requests.get(some_url)

The output will tell if a variable is needed. If so, just replace it with the correct variable(s) and your done.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got a sitemap with all the URLs, so I can just loop over that. It was more a question of whether I have to write a script and GET each page, or whether I can just hit something in memcached or Django that does this for me.